# Tables can't be generated using spring boot

Tags: spring, jpa

I don't have any error but i can not generate the database ,here's what i have in console :

```
2015-05-14 16:23:23.655  INFO 4580 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.8.Final}
2015-05-14 16:23:23.663  INFO 4580 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2015-05-14 16:23:23.670  INFO 4580 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2015-05-14 16:23:24.218  INFO 4580 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2015-05-14 16:23:25.307  INFO 4580 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2015-05-14 16:23:25.466  INFO 4580 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory    : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2015-05-14 16:23:25.817  INFO 4580 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2015-05-14 16:23:25.825  INFO 4580 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
2015-05-14 16:23:26.508  INFO 4580 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@20d04b: startup date [Thu May 14 16:23:13 CEST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-05-14 16:23:26.790  INFO 4580 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2015-05-14 16:23:26.791  INFO 4580 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[text/html],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2015-05-14 16:23:26.878  INFO 4580 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2015-05-14 16:23:26.878  INFO 4580 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2015-05-14 16:23:27.038  INFO 4580 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2015-05-14 16:23:27.617  INFO 4580 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2015-05-14 16:23:27.832  INFO 4580 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2015-05-14 16:23:27.837  INFO 4580 --- [           main] demo.DemoJpaTApplication                 : Started DemoJpaTApplication in 15.327 seconds (JVM running for 16.798)
```

Here's my 2 entities :database and Entities  (i have many entities belong to one database)

```
package entities;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;

import javax.persistence.OneToMany;


@Entity
public class Database implements Serializable {
    private int id_database;
    private String database_name;
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="id_entity")
    private Collection <Entities> entities;
    public int getId_database() {
        return id_database;
    }
    public void setId_database(int id_database) {
        this.id_database = id_database;
    }
    public String getDatabase_name() {
        return database_name;
    }
    public void setDatabase_name(String database_name) {
        this.database_name = database_name;
    }
    public Database() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public Database(int id_database, String database_name) {
        super();
        this.id_database = id_database;
        this.database_name = database_name;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Database [id_database=" + id_database + ", database_name="
                + database_name + "]";
    }



}





    package entities;

    import java.io.Serializable;

    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
    @Entity
    public class Entities implements Serializable {
        private int id_entity;
        private String entity_name;
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="id_database")
        private Database d;
        public int getId_entity() {
            return id_entity;
        }
        public void setId_entity(int id_entity) {
            this.id_entity = id_entity;
        }
        public String getEntity_name() {
            return entity_name;
        }
        public void setEntity_name(String entity_name) {
            this.entity_name = entity_name;
        }

    }
```

Here's my application.properties where i mentioned the connection and its details ,the driver ....,i am following  the offical documentation of spring boot

```
      # DataSourcesettings: 
        spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_hajar
        spring.datasource.username= root
        spring.datasource.password=
        spring.datasource.driverClassName= com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        # Specifythe DBMS
        spring.jpa.database = MYSQL
        # Show or not log for each sqlquery
        spring.jpa.show-sql = true 
        # Hibernateddlauto (create, create-drop, update)
        spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto =update
        # Namingstrategy
        spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
        spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
        # ViewResolver
        spring.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/views/
        spring.view.suffix: .jsp
```

Comment: Try other dialect `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect` or `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set ddl-auto property to create or create-drop?

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create
```